# Stats for Birthright's The Spider that are compatible with 5e

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, conversion

Looking for D&D 5e stats for The Spider in Birthright. A conversion from an earlier edition, if there ever was published stats for The Spider, or a suggestion of a reasonable stats for 5e will be welcome. A perfect answer will contain enough information to run a combat encounter with The Spider and include any items that the Spider is known for having and that the spider would bring to a combat situation.

Answer (score 1):

I did this some time ago for a 5e Birthright campaign in the Southern Coast.
Unfortunately I didn't have the opportunity to test in since the campaign didn't start.

[image]

Spiderfell Army (as per UA mass combat rules)

- Goblin Spider Riders, 2 Units, 10 stands of Goblin Skirmishers and 10 stands of Goblin Spider Riders. (200 goblin skirmishers, 100 goblin spider riders)
- Goblin Irregulars, 4 Units, 10 stands of Goblin Skirmishers. (400 goblin skirmishers)
- Giant Spiders Swarm, 2 Units, 10 stands of Giant Spiders. (100 giant spiders)
- Gnoll Infantry, 2 Units, 10 stands of Gnoll Infantry. (200 gnoll infantry)
- Gnoll Cavalry, 2 Units, 10 stands of Gnoll Cavalry. (100 gnoll cavalry)
- Gnoll Irregulars, 2 Units, 10 stands of Gnoll Marauders. (200 gnoll marauders)

*Statblock created with http://thegeniusinc.com/dd-monster-maker-download/ using Valloric's statblock template.

Comment: [Homebrew answers must be tested and backed by experience.](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5153/is-homebrew-an-acceptable-answer-to-a-question)

Comment: Thank you. The statblock looks very nice I'll definitely check that out, thank you for adding the url. It would be very nice if you could say a few words about why you made the stats the way you did. I have started on my own version. My current thinking is start with the goblin boss from dmg, add some bonuse to stats since he was the boss of the bosses. Give him a few level of barbarian, then deismar. Boost stats appropriate for the awnsheg template, and level up a bit more. Give him a nice selection of magical items. Therefor interested in understanding your thinking

Comment: You're welcome. I've started with the CR range I would meet. The Spider, even if it's not the most powerful awnshegh, is still a fearful opponent for characters just entered the "masters of the realm" tier (11-16 level), so I set the CR 15. It's in line with the HD and XP for the Spider in AD&D (13HD / XP 14,000).

Comment: I used the Drider as the basis for AC, Speed, Stats, Skills, Attacks and Abilities related to spiders and webs, increasing skills bonus, attacks bonus and damage to match CR 15. Then I've looked at the signature abilities in AD&D, trying to replicate them with something similar in 5e: deadly leap by the bulette, blinding spittle by the gibbering mouther and web by the giant spider. I finally added the bloodline abilities (in my campaign are similar to the invocations of warlocks, with virtually the same effect as AD&D ones).

Comment: No magical items since the original Spider doesn't use any in combat (but I guess it could have something, considering its Domain Treasure). PS. Sorry I'd to split my comment since it was too long. I've also edited the first post, since the language "yeti" should read "telepaty 120', only with spiders", but I've deleted it and I've added the ability "spider telepaty" based on "shark telepaty" for the sahuagin.

Comment: I tried the stats in my campaign yesterday. Before we started I was pretty sure that the spiders stats as presented above were too week to be cr 15. story-wise I was happy to let my players kill the spider, so I used them any way.  My party of four level 8th characters had the spider down in two rounds where the spider started the combat by doing Deadly leap as a surprise action in the round before. The siders goal in my fight was to kill one cleric that was butchering his goblin army with guardian spirits. After two rounds the 8th lvl cleric was still standing and the spider dead.

Comment: They hit him with almost every attack, and the spider actually had the lowest AC in the fight. Even the wizard using mage armour had higher AC. Also his melee attacks are very weak. The paladin in the group did 2-3 more damage on the spider than the spider was able to do to the cleric with claw attacks. Bite did a decent amount of damage, but the cleric made the save and "only" took about 35 in damage from poison + bite.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, unfortunately I noted that there was a typo and AC was lower than the correct one (it should be 19, as the Drider). AC 16 is the right one for CR 8/9, despite there are some creatures in MM with AC 16 and CR higher. Did you use the blood abilities and Legendary actions? In the CR calculation the Spider has Prof. bonus in line with CR 15, Armor Class for CR 17, Hit Points for CR 8, Attack Bonus for CR 16, Damage/Round for CR 11, and Save DC for CR 7.

Comment: It could have sense to rise Hit Points to 200l, Damage/Round to 86 and Save DC to 17 to have it more "deadly", as it should be against 4 characters of 8th level. Will review the template above accordingly.